# Running as admin sometimes

Tags: c#, windows-vista, uac

I have a program that needs to run as a normal user most of the time, but once in a while I need to stop and start a service. How do I go about making a program that runs as a normal user most of the time but elevates into administrator mode for some function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't elevate a process once its running but you could either :-

### Restart the process as elevated

```
private void elevateCurrentProcess()
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;       
    startInfo.FileName = Application.ExecutablePath;
    startInfo.Verb = "runas";

    try
    {
        Process p = Process.Start(startInfo);
    }
    catch
    {
        // User didn't allow UAC
        return;
    }
    Application.Exit();
}
```

This method means that your process continues to run elevated and no more UAC promopts - both a good and a bad thing, depends upon your audience.

### Put the code that requires elevation into a seperate exe

Set the manifest as requireAdministrator and start it as a separate process. See this [sample code](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2cd92e43-6cda-478a-9e3b-4f831e899433&DisplayLang=en)

This method means a UAC prompt every time you run the operation.

Best method depends upon your audience (admin types or not) and frequency of the elevated operation.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you need to start a seperate process that runs as the administrator. You can't elevate a process once it's already been started.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78696/vista-uac-access-elevation-and-net).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use what is referred to as Impersonation..

[http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158][1]

The above shows how it would be accomplished for an ASP.Net app, but the code is probably near identical for your needs.

Comment: I don't think this will work for the desktop but it is still going to be useful for other projects.