# About UAC in vista

Tags: windows-vista, uac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vista UAC, Access Elevation and .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78696/vista-uac-access-elevation-and-net)

I have a special feature in my AP, this feature need to get administrator right in Vista. Is there any MS API to pop up the UAC dialog when I click the button? Because I don’t want the end-user to see UAC dialog during startup, the feature is really special, not every user will do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78696/vista-uac-access-elevation-and-net).

Answer (score 0):

Nope, MS has spent lots of time to make programmatic access to that button impossible! If you could do such a thing, UAC would be absolutely useless. You might encapsulate the functionality as a something (e.g. a Windows service) running with admin privileges. on which you'll call a method from the non-elevated process.

Comment: I think he wants to elevate his process in the middle of it, as discussed here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78696/vista-uac-access-elevation-and-net

Comment: But this doesn't make the process click that "continue" button. And after elevation, the process will be elevated forever which is not what the question asks.