# STOP Application Pool Issue Programmatically IIS7

Tags: c#

In my application I needs to stop a application pool programmatically in IIS 7. I have created a local account and given him Administrative Priviledges. Here is the code

```
Private static void StopApplication()
{
    string serviceHostDeploymentType = "local";
        if (serviceHostDeploymentType.Equals("local"))
        {
            WindowsIdentityImpersonate newIdentity = new WindowsIdentityImpersonate();
            if (newIdentity.Impersonate("AccountName", Environment.MachineName, "Password"))
            {
                try
                {
                    ServerManager serverManager = ServerManager.OpenRemote("Server");
                    string siteName = GetWebSiteNameById(serverManager, 1);
                    Site parentWebsite = serverManager.Sites[siteName];

                    if (parentWebsite != null)
                    {
                        ApplicationPool apppool = serverManager.ApplicationPools["Application Pool Name"];

                        if (apppool != null)
                        {
                            apppool.Stop();
                        }
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    newIdentity.Undo();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
           throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("...");
        }
    }
```

I am getting an error Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

```
Stack Trace

    at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Interop.IAppHostMethodInstance.Execute()
       at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElement.ExecuteMethod(String methodName)
       at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ApplicationPool.Stop()
       at ServerManagerTesting.Form1.StopApplication()
       at ServerManagerTesting.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at ServerManagerTesting.Program.Main()
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Answer (score 0):

The likely problem is that UAC is preventing you to control IIS. Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78696/vista-uac-access-elevation-and-net). The chosen answer has nothing to do with your own question, but other answers point to an SDK sample that launches a new process with elevated privileges.

Comment: I also think its a problem with UAC, but other than adding the user into adminstrator group what else do I have to do make it work

Comment: When I Run the application from "Run As", it does run. But this code is within a service on IIS. How can I make it run. Impersonate does not work when called from service.

Comment: Please follow the advice on the quoted question. It shows how to launch a new process with the needed privileges enabled.