# Can a non-elevated Windows process request elevation later in execution?

Tags: windows, uac, administrator, elevated-privileges

I'm running a program installed in Program Files, which of course is read-only without elevation. For some download-on-first-use features of the program, I'd like to download new files to the installation directory. That requires elevation. If possible, how do I elevate the current process to do the copy?

I could launch a separate process to do the installation but that seems cumbersome. I can't find anything in my searches about elevating a process (permanently or temporarily) except when the process starts. If that's how Windows elevation is designed, fine, I just haven't been able to find that definitively in documentation or Q&A.

Comment: You can't elevate your own already-running process.  But there is another option besides restarting elevated and trying to transfer your entire state: An out-of-process DCOM object can be elevated, and through the magic of marshaling, appear like it's part of your unelevated process.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/93379/103167